# How to do strict boolean comparison in Excel?

Tags: excel

How to do strict boolean comparison in Excel?

I have cells that contain `TRUE` or `FALSE`, as well as other blank cells.

I want to format the cell only if the value is exactly `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

I do not want blank cells to be treated as `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**>I want to format the cell only if the value is exactly TRUE or FALSE**

Do you mean in a single condition or separately?

If you want to format if A1 is `TRUE` **OR** `FALSE` try

`=ISLOGICAL(A1)`

for `FALSE` only try

`=AND(ISLOGICAL(A1),A1=FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do "Text that contains" and then "false".

I'm talking about when you click on the "Conditional Formatting" button, "Highlight Cells Rules", "Text that contains"